# Maven Unable to Find Dependencies For Stash Plugin

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to make a Stash (Bitbucket Server) hook following [this tutorial.](https://developer.atlassian.com/stash/docs/latest/how-tos/creating-a-stash-plugin.html)

I installed the Atlassian SDK and ran both `atlas-create-stash-plugin` and `atlas-create-stash-plugin-module`.

However, Maven is unable to find any dependencies, despite them being in my local repository. I mean, look at this screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the dependencies have successfully been installed to my local Maven repo, but IntelliJ (and Maven when I try to compile the plugin) are unable to locate the dependencies. Why?

Comment: What's the pom file look like?

Comment: @Compass https://pastebin.com/wjmrAc80 - This was auto-generated by `atlas-create-stash-plugin`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be cache issue. So please try to do following in Intellij Idea:

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.
```

Also, you can try to reimport your project: [image]

Comment: That's what I thought, too. Unfortunately that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try point to the repository and maven of Atlassian SDK installation:

[image]